# Worst-case one-way permutations under P different from NP

Tags: one-way-function, permutation, computational-complexity-theory

This is probably obvious, but I cannot find it anywhere, since all textbooks define OWFs for average-case hardness.

Do we known if *worst-case* one-way *permutations* exist assuming $\mathbf{P} \neq \mathbf{NP}$? I don't require average-case hardness, it suffices that the function is hard to invert in the worst-case. That is, assuming $\mathbf{P} \neq \mathbf{NP}$, is there a family of permutations $f_n : \{0,1\}^n \to \{ 0,1\}^n$, such that $f_n$ can be computed by circuits of size polynomial in $n$ but there is no family of poly-size circuits that inverts $f_n$ on all of its outputs?. (I stated for circuits, but I’m happy with the uniform setting too). I’d also be happy if the output space is a bit larger than $\{0,1\}^n$ as long as each $f_n$ is injective.

Comment: Can you be more precise with what you mean by worst case one-wayness? Is the worst case over the choice of function or over the choice of input?

Comment: @lamontap I edited the question, I hope it’s a bit more clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following paper shows that worst-case one-way permutations exist if and only if $\textsf{P} \ne \textsf{UP} \cap \textsf{coUP}$. A problem is in $\textsf{UP}$ if all yes-instances have exactly one witness, and all no-instances have no witnesses. $\textsf{UP}$ is a subset of $\textsf{NP}$.

> Christopher M. Homan and Mayur Thakur, [One-way permutations and self-witnessing languages.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82120146.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.